# Is there a way to set an abbreviation in a modeline so it is always available local to one file buffer?

Tags: abbreviations, modeline

I have a handful of files (LaTeX documents) that have one specific proper name that is really obnoxious to type out but used frequently. I've eased the pain of this with an abbreviation like so:

```
iab Eİ Elçilerin İşleri
```

This works great, but I don't want to pollute my global vimrc with document specific hacks like this. Is there a way to set an abbrieviation in the modeline? I tried appending it as is, but modelines appear to only work with `set` commands.

Comment: `iab <buffer> E...`?

Comment: @muru That doesn't work from a modeline.

Comment: This specific scenario is calling for `\newcommand{\EI}{Elçilerin İşleri}`

Comment: @Gilles I actually started out with that, but it has a couple drawbacks. One is that it makes post-processing harder. There are a couple of scripts that keep track of what gets referenced where (that checks an API to validate the references) and doing this against the TeX source is a lot easier that having to compile it and run against the formatted output.

Comment: Would it work to define a filetype for those files and set the filetype in the modeline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it has been said, it's not possible by design.

If you want something like modelines, you'll have to write your own plugin. In the early 2000 I wrote [let-modeline](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/let-modeline.vim) that decodes a slightly different format of modelines (i.e. `Vim: let var=expr`) to set variables.

For something more complex than a variable, I'd also use a local vimrc. However I wouldn't use `.exrc` that works only for files in the same directory where the `.exrc` file is. Plugins like [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) support hierarchies of directories.

Answer (score 12):

`:help modeline` is pretty specific about this:

> No other commands than "set" are supported, for security reasons (somebody
>   might create a Trojan horse text file with modelines).  And not all options
>   can be set.  For some options a flag is set, so that when it's used the
>   |sandbox| is effective[...]
>
> Hint: If you would like to do something else than setting an option, you could
>   define an autocommand that checks the file for a specific string.  For
>   example:
>
> ```
>    au BufReadPost * if getline(1) =~ "VAR" | call SetVar() | endif
> ```
>
> And define a function SetVar() that does something with the line containing
>   "VAR".

If you're looking for a workaround, you could try using a local `.vimrc` with `:set exrc`. Before doing so, be sure to consider the security implications mentioned in `:help 'exrc'`.