# Is it possible to create custom "set" commands in my rc file and call them from a modeline?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, modeline

I recently [asked a question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2547/267) in which I learned that it is not possible to pass anything except parameters to `:set` in vim modelines. I understand the security concerns, but I'm wondering if there isn't another way around this. A [recent question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29097673/313192) about setting large batches of parameters to comply with a coding standard got me to thinking—would it be possible to define a "group" of things in my rc file that can be turned on or off from the modeline?

Excuse the pseudo code, but is there a way to create a function that is triggered from a set parameter?

```
set_function! codestyle()
    if &1 == 'psr-2'
        set ts=4
        set sw=4
    endfi
    if &1 == 'drupal7'
        set ts=2
        set sw=2
        iab D8 Drupal 8
    endif
endset_function
```

This could then be triggered by a modeline such as

```
# vim: codestyle=psr-2
```

This would be in some ways be similar to file type matching, but allow manual overrides. It would also setting up the environment in other pre-defined ways, avoiding the security issues of having a file run other arbitrary commands in vim but allowing a more customized environment. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This would require defining your own option for `set` ;  AFAIK, this is not possible in Vim ...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Does that mean the answer to this question is that vimscript cannot wrapper or otherwise extend built-in functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a few choices.

1. First one: You can write your own kind of modeline decoder, i.e. a plugin. This is a very similar answer to the one I gave to your other question.

   Indeed, we cannot add new vim options (that can be set with `:set`), but we can add new variables. And we cannot use the standard modelines to do more than setting vim options.
2. Second possibility: [let-modeline](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/master/plugin/let-modeline.vim) could be exploited through the *callback* feature to call one function or another. You could have your `CodeStyle()` function in your `.vimrc` or a (autoload?) plugin, then have your files contains:

   ```
   # VIM: let b:codestyle='psr-2' b:ModeLine_CallBack='CodeStyle'
   ```

   But if your need is this precise and if you really don't want plugins like [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc), then write your own modeline-like decoder.
3. The third, and IMO, better choice in that case would be to define a new filetype and set `'ft'` to this filetype in modelines with: `# vim: set ft=php.psr2`. With `php` being the global usual filetype (I'm not sure about this one), and `psr2` being the specialized filetype that'll correspond to your coding styles. You'll have to define two ftplugins: ftplugin/psr2.vim and and ftplugin/drupal7.vim where you'll put your calls to `:setlocal` (and not `:set`).

Comment: Upvoted for option 3. I think this is the most semantically appropriate and Vim-suitable approach.